# Filter with Advanced Custom Field in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to set filters based on Advanced Custom Fields in my WordPress site. Basically my advanced custom field named as 'ispremium' has two values as 'yes' and 'no'  and in dropdown filter I have set two options as 'Premium Only' And 'All Programs'.

I need to do when 'Premium Only' dropdown option is selected it will list all the post having value 'ispremium'='yes' and when all program is selected it will list both 'ispremium=yes' and 'ispremium='no'. I have following code but it is listing post with 'ispremium=yes' always. What's wrong in my code?

```
<select name="order" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <?php
        $order_options = array(
            'yes' => 'Premium Only',
            'no' => 'All Programs',
        );

        $result = query_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'ispremium',
        'value' => 'yes',          
        ),
        ) ) );

        $result = query_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'ispremium',
        'value' => 'yes','no'          
        ),
        ) ) );


        foreach( $order_options as $result => $label ) {
            echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['value'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts()`. You also have some syntax errors like `'value' => 'yes','no'`.

### For premium only:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'ispremium',
            'value'     => 'yes',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### All Programs

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'ispremium',
            'value'     => 'yes',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'ispremium',
            'value'     => 'no',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Check [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) for further info. Also, I suggest you to do this with Ajax, since if you put this code within your `select` element, the available options are going to be the from the last query made, and won't be dynamic on field change.

But I don't totally get what you're trying to do though; you'll probably want to show the available programs in another drop down, or you could simply redirect to another archive page which lists the programs accordingly to the selected option.

Comment: hi thanks for your help.Actually I just want to update the program list in the same page.Do u have any idea about how can i keep the sticky and premium post at top always yet after filtering

Comment: In that case, you will need to _isolate_ the query. Meaning that the query that you create with the above example will update the posts in the  `<div class="dynamic-posts"></div>` (for instance), while the  `<div class="sticky-posts"></div>` will have the posts queried as _premium only_. If you won't use Ajax, you'll need query vars to get the values in the query `$args`.